# 10 By 10 Array - Previous Arrays Get Overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a basic function that creates a 10 by 10 array with random D's and E's as values. My code is as follows:

```
function tenByTen(){
    var outerArr = [];
    var arrInArr = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            if((Math.floor(Math.random() *10) +1) % 2 == 0){
                arrInArr[j] = ("D");
            } else {
                arrInArr[j] = ("E");
            }
        }
        outerArr[i] = arrInArr;
    }

    return outerArr;
}
```

When this executes, the output shows 10 arrays with the same 10 values. It seems that the values in `arrInArr` are getting overwritten but why would the new values update the arrays that are already in `outerArr`?

If I add `arrInArr = []` right below `arr[i] = arrInArr`, the function behaves as it should. Can anyone please explain why this is the case? Is it because by redeclaring `arrInArr` to be equal to an empty array, the function is accessing a new memory bank?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Yes, because in your posted code, you keep modifying the same `arrInArr` over and over again. Redeclaring the temporary variable (`arrInArr` in your case) inside loop is a good idea at many times.

Comment: Read your code again, count how many array have you created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two misconceptions that cause your confusion. The first is you're doing:

```
outerArr[i] = arrInArr;
```

I presume, since you're doing this, that you assume that you're assigning the value of `arrInArr` to `outerArr[i]`. However this is not the case. What you have to realize is that `arrInArr` is a pointer to an array. Therefore the code above merely copies a reference to `arrInArr` to `outerArr[i]`. There is only one `arrInArr` so they all point to the same array.

Second, you seem to believe that this:

```
var arrInArr = [];
```

Is merely declaring an array variable. What you seem to be ignoring is the code after the `=` sign. The above code is exactly identical to:

```
var arrInArr = new Array();
```

So it is not merely declaring a variable, it is also creating an array object. This explains why moving it in the for loop makes the code work: you're creating a new array object for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: The key is that arrays (just like all objects in JavaScript)  are passed by reference. So at each iteration you fill the with new values and then add a pointer to it.

Comment: @wapsee: Not just passed by reference, they ARE references. In this particular example there is no passing of variables into functions so pass by reference does not apply.

Comment: Thanks SOOO much slebetman. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Straight to the point and easy to understand. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, just to make sure that I understand this. So arrInArr is just a pointer to a single array object and I'm storing a copy of that array 10 times in my outerArray which is why when I change the value of an index in one array, it changes the value at that index for all of the arrays? So I need "arrInArr = []" to create a new Array object which arrInArr then points to? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That's basically it.